# I need to access a new window which pops after a button is clicked

Tags: reactjs, automated-tests, cypress

I need to access the new window which pops after a button is clicked.

I used `cy.get('.app-card__content').click()` to click on the button called `Create a new plugin`. After I click on the button the App is created on a new window and I do not know how to get the window and continue my test.

This new window URL is dynamic and every time anyone clicks on it the number which is App ID increases.

For example:

https://www.website.io/apps/app_name/standalone?id=DYNAMIC_ID_NUMBER

I was able to log into the website and create a new App, however, I don't know how to grab the new window with the URL.

I could not get this code to work:

```
describe('window open', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    cy.visit('/index.html', {
      onBeforeLoad(win) {
        cy.stub(win, 'open').as('windowOpen')
      }
    })
  })

  it('see window open being called with url', function () {
    cy.get('#open-window').click()

    cy.get('@windowOpen').should('be.calledWith', 'page1.html')
  })
})


Here is the code I wrote:

// This test consists of Accessing Staging and Create a new App.
// Go to website.io.
describe('Staging Test v1', function(){
    it('Accessing Staging', function(){
        cy.visit('https://www.website.io')
        cy.wait(2000)
    })

    // Get login button.
    it('Get login button', function(){
        cy.get('.signed-out-container > .signInTab').click()
        cy.wait(2000)
    })

    // Fill out the modal and log in
    it('Fill out the modal and log in', function(){
        cy.get('#sign_in_email').type('user@website.io', {delay:110}).should('have.value', 'user@website.io')
        cy.wait(1000)

        cy.get('#new_sign_in_password').type('password', {delay:110}).should('have.value', 'password')
        cy.wait(1000)

        cy.get('#sign-in-submit').click()
        cy.wait(6000)
    })

    // Click on new Create New Plugin button.
    it('Click on create a new plugin button', function(){
        cy.get('.dashboard-header__create-new-container > .button').should('be.visible').click({force:true})
        cy.wait(2000)
    })

    // Search and create a new App
    it('Search and create a new App', function(){
        
        cy.get('.app-search__search-input').click({force:true}).type('App name', {force:true})
        cy.wait(3000)
        cy.get('.app-card__content').click()
        cy.wait(10000)
    })

    // Grab the new window to continue the test

    // Need to find out how to grab the new window passing along cookies and sessions to remain logged in.

    // Develop part 2 of the test
    

})
```

I need to create a new App which pops on a new window, grab the new window and continue the rest of the test.

I also need to remain logged in on the new window as I need to save the App.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, you can't handle more than one tab/window in a Cypress test. Just have a look at this part of the Documentation:

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs.html#Multiple-tabs

When I faced this, I used the workarounds they offer for this, so you don't have the need to 'grab' other windows; If you can, go for this one:

```
// We can remove the offending attribute - target='_blank'
// that would normally open content in a new tab.
  cy.get('.app-card__content').invoke('removeAttr', 'target').click()
```

Of course you can only use this if your element does have that attribute.

Have a look at this other solutions they provide for this topic: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/testing-dom__tab-handling-links/cypress/integration/tab_handling_anchor_links_spec.js

Answer (score 2):

I just solved a similar issue. Maybe you can use it as a reference.
In my case, the new window opens after clicking a button, and the url is dynamic.

```
cy.window().then(win => {
    cy.stub(win, 'open').as('windowOpen');
});

// you can try exclude the 'should' below
// in my code it worked without this 'should' first
// after merging the latest changes this part failed somehow though no change was made here
// after investigation I found that the stub argument was not ready immediately
// so I added 'should' here to wait the argument load
// before visiting the url contained within it

cy.get('@windowOpen').should('be.calledWith', Cypress.sinon.match.string).then(stub => {
    cy.visit(stub.args[0][0]);
    stub.restore;
});
```